# Codeigniter 4 Multisite

Tags: .htaccess, multisite, codeigniter-4

I have installed Codeigniter 4 on Raspbian and everything seems to be working fine.
My web directory is `/var/www/html`
Inside there are two folders containing two different Codeigniter-4 apps that I would like to invoke with:

- `blue.ddns.net` -> `/var/www/html/blue/public/index.php`
- `black.ddns.net` -> `/var/www/html/black/public/index.php`

So I'm creating a `.htaccess` file to put in the folder `/var/www/html/` to handle the two requests

Well, I'm still at step 0 because I can't get the `.htaccess` file to work properly.

Below I attach a copy of the file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /var/www/html
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blue/public/index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

The Rewrite module is activated
the error that appears in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` is:

> ```
> /var/www/html/.htaccess: Expected </IfModule> before end of configuration, referer: https://blue.ddns.net/
> ```

Comment: Please add your server config / vHost container(s) to your question. Are you attempting to do this with a single vHost for both hostnames (as it looks like here)? Or separate vHost configs for each hostname (which is recommended and assumed by the current answer)?

Comment: But the error you are seeing suggests you are missing a closing `</IfModule` directive - which is not evident in the directives you've posted.

Comment: You should also remove the `RewriteBase` directive entirely. The argument to the `RewriteBase` directive is a URL-path, not a filesystem path. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase

Answer (score 2):

That shouldn't really be done in your htaccess. You should setup that in your apache virtual hosts.

Go into your sites-avaiable folder.

```
$ cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
```

Create a new virtual host called blue.ddns.net.conf

```
$ touch blue.ddns.net.conf
```

Open that file with nano or any other text editor you might like and add the following.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin your@email.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/blue/public
        ServerName blue.ddns.net
        ServerAlias blue.ddns.net
        <Directory "/var/www/html/blue/public">
                allow from all
                AllowOverride All
                Options None
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        RewriteEngine on
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =blue.ddns.net
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Save and close the file.

Then add this to your apache with the following:

```
$ sudo micro blue.ddns.net.conf
```

Repeat the same process for the other codeigniter install and reboot apache.

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

That should do it.

Now if you want to override some config that would be something that you might do in your htaccess file for each codeigniter 4 install.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I followed your mini-tutorial but nothing seems to change:
Both calling https://blue.ddns.net and calling https://black.ddns.net I always see the same thing: my /var/www/html (browsable) folder.
I've tried both with and without an .htaccess file in the /var/www/html folder

Comment: This answer does assume you have an SSL cert installed and another `<VirtualHost *:443>` container that actually does the work. Other notes on the `<VirtualHost *:80>` container as posted... the `ServerAlias` directive is superfluous. You shouldn't be using `Allow from all` _and_ `Require all granted`. Assuming this is Apache 2.4 then only the later is required. `Options None` - should be `Options FollowSymLinks` since mod_rewrite is being used. But mod_rewrite is not required here (you certainly don't need to check the `SERVER_NAME`), a simple `Redirect` is sufficient and preferred.

Comment: @MrWhite: thanks for the answer. Yes, I have installed Let'sEncrypt with a permanent redirect from HTTP to HTTPS

Comment: @360degree From the suggestion posted here, `/var/www/html` should not be browsable and your `.htaccess` file should go in the respective `DocumentRoot`, not `/var/www/html`. (Obviously, you'll need to adjust your `.htaccess` file accordingly.)

Comment: @MrWhite: I currently no longer have an htaccess (nothing changed). Sorry but this is the first time I've dealt with Apache a little more in depth. I seriously need a hand to create it properly. As long as there is a need to create it

Comment: If you redirected your traffic to https your virtual hosts must be configured to port 443 and not 80.

Answer (score 2):

I've always worked in hosting and never had to do Apache configurations.
But now I'm discovering the Raspberry/Linux world.
Thanks to your answers I was able to better understand the problem and solve it (for the moment) in the following way:

Now my configuration files `000-default.conf` (port 80) and `000-default-le-ssl.conf` (port 443) both contain the following code:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">.
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

in `/var/www/html` instead I created a .htaccess file with the following code:

```
# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>.
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "black\.ddns\.net"
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ black/public/index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "blue\.ddns\.net"
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blue/public/index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

apps are located in

```
/var/www/html/blue
```

and
/var/www/html/black

It's a very simple solution that serves my purposes.
Although I think it's not very elegant
What do you think about it?

Comment: So, you're not using _any_ virtual hosts?

Comment: I tried to use a virtual host with no success. I'll try again. For now my .htaccess doesn't work if I invoke an existing file. Even if I put 

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

Comment: Virtual hosts are really essential if you want to have more than 1 "separate" website. Those `RewriteCond` directives would need to go before each `RewriteRule` in your code above.